# Show $\frac{n+1}{2n^2+2} \in O(\frac{1}{n})$ without limits

Tags: calculus

$\frac{n+1}{2n^2+2} \in O(\frac{1}{n})$ without limits

$\frac{n+1}{2n^2+2} \leq \frac{n+n}{2n^2 + 2} \leq \frac{2n}{2n^2 + 2}$

Not sure how to lower the denominator

Comment: Are we allowed to use calculus? Because you can show the point (the $n_0$) where, with a sufficiently large $c$ (multiplying factor), that $\frac{n + 1}{2n^2 + 2} \leq c\frac{1}{n}$, for all $n > n_0$.

Comment: And if not, you can just choose a fairly large $n_0$...it might also help to factor out $n$: $\frac{n}{n^2}\frac{1 + \frac{1}{n}}{2 + \frac{2}{n^2}}$.

Comment: Note that $2n^2\lt2n^2+2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $n + 1 \le n + n = 2n$ for all $n \ge 1$, so
$$
\frac{n+1}{2n^2+2} \le \frac{n}{n^2+1}.
$$
Now notice that $n^2 + 1 > n^2$, so if $n \ge 1$,
$$
\frac{n+1}{2n^2+2} \le \frac{n}{n^2+1} < \frac{n}{n^2} = \frac{1}{n},
$$
as desired.